# How to Right Align Elements in Navbar with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble right aligning elements in my navbar with bootstrap. For some reason, the elements seemed fixed and even using an external css file did not help. The look im aiming for is keeping the logo and name or "brand" on the left, with the rest of the 'items' right-aligned. For some reason, the 'ml-auto' class of bootstrap is not working either.

HTML:

```css
.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar" width="100%">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img
                        src="/com_connect_font.png"
                        class="me-2"
                        height="70"
                        alt=""
                        loading="lazy"
                        />
                        <medium>Community Connector</medium>
                    </a>
                    <button
                        class="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
                        data-mdb-target="#navbarNav"
                        aria-controls="navbarNav"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    >
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                              About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                              Contacts
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                              Settings
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>
        </div>


       
    </body>
</html>
```

Could someone share what might be the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small example. Only bootstrap classes without any additional CSS. In your example, the first div destroys the nav because it's not 100% wide. Btw here's another example. In your navbar the whole mobile view is broken. The example below is completely working with desktop and mobile devices.

Hopefully it will work :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

           <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
        <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"><!-- hidden spacer to center brand on mobile --></span>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Navbar 7
        </a>
        <div class="w-100 text-right">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar7">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="myNavbar7">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


       
    </body>
</html>
```